# If $V=V^+\oplus V^-$, then in an orthonormal basis, the number of negative definite vectors is $\dim(V^-)$

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I've read about Sylvester's Law of Inertia which states that for any scalar product space $(V,g)$, we have subspaces $V^+,V^-$ such that $V=V^+\oplus V^-$ and $g$ is positive definite on $V^+$ and negative definite on $V^-$. The dimensions of these subspaces are uniquely defined by $g$.

$\dim(V^-)\equiv\nu$ is called the index of $g$, which is obviously well-defined. I've also understood the result that there exists an orthonormal basis for every scalar product space. It is claimed that the number of vectors $e_i$ in the orthonormal basis such that $\langle e_i,e_i\rangle=-1$ is $\nu$, but without proof.

I thought maybe if I could show that the subset of **all** negative definite basis vectors (say $(e_1,\ldots,e_{\nu})$) forms the basis of $V^-$, then that would naturally lead to the above result. But I run into some trouble. Taking a very simple example, if we just have a 2D space $V$ with ON basis $(e_1,e_2)$ where $\langle e_1,e_1\rangle=1$ and $\langle e_2,e_2\rangle=-1$, then $v=e_1+2e_2$ would be such that $\langle v,v\rangle<0$. So I can't show that all nonzero negative definite vectors are spanned solely by the negative definite subset of the ON basis.

What am I missing/where am I going wrong?

(P.S. by negative definite $v$, I just mean that $g$ is negative definite on $\{v\}$ to save typing effort)

Comment: Saying the set of all negative-definite basis vectors forms a basis for $V^-$ is about as true as saying the set of all nonzero vectors in the usual $\Bbb R^n$ forms a basis. You're talking about an uncountably infinite set! Also your claim that $V^+$ and $V^-$ are uniquely defined by $g$ is false...

Comment: @runway44: What I meant was: there exists an orthonormal basis for $(V,g)$. I mentioned that my thought process was that all the vectors in that basis, on whom $g$ is negative definite, may form a basis for $V^-$. Also I said that the _dimensions_ of $V^+$ and $V^-$ are uniquely defined, not the subspaces themselves.

Comment: Ah, skimming I missed the word dimensions. Unless your pseudo-orthonormal basis is constructed specifically from bases for $V^+$ and $V^-$, it will not be true that the positive and negative elements of the basis span $V^+$ and $V^-$. Moreover, there are vastly more positive vectors than are in any particular $V^+$, and same for negative vectors and $V^-$, so the fact your $v=e_1+2e_2$ is negative but not in $V^-$ is not an issue.

Comment: @runway44: Ah I see. Thanks for clearing up the misconception in the latter part of the question. So can I use this logic: If I denote the subspace spanned by the negative vectors of that orthonormal basis as $W^-$ and the one spanned by the positive vectors of that same ON basis as $W^+$, and then further show that $V=W^+\oplus W^-$ - then I'm done. And in turn to do this, since clearly $V=W^++W^-$, I'd need to show that $W^+\cap W^-=\{0\}$

Comment: Yes. It's also fun showing if $V=A^+\oplus A^-=B^+\oplus B^-$ then $\dim A^+=\dim B^+$ and $\dim A^-=\dim B^-$.